# How to format '7' to produce '007'

Tags: python, number-formatting

How would you format '7' to print '007' here:

```
>>> number = 7
>>> print(number)
7
```

Ideally, there'd something similar to always showing these decimal places?:

```
>>> number = 7
>>> print("{:.2f}".format(number))
7.00
```

I've searched online for a similar solution to this but can't seem to find anything in this format...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: A possible solution, https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-add-leading-zeros-to-a-number-in-python

Comment: ```str(number).zfill(3)```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to cast 7 using `str()` and finally use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) to add leading zeros:

> Return a copy of the string left filled with ASCII `'0'` digits to make
>   a string of length width. A leading sign prefix (`'+'`/`'-'`) is handled
>   by inserting the padding after the sign character rather than before.
>   The original string is returned if width is less than or equal to
>   `len(s)`.

---

```
str(7).zfill(3)
>>> '007'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
print("{0:0=3d}".format(number))
```